How to change number of decimal places in Sketch dimensions?
I'm having troubles figuring out how to change displayed number of decimal places in Siemens NX.
By default, Siemens NX rounds decimal places to one. Actual dimension values are right, when you edit dimensions all decimal places are there. But number representing this dimension in Sketch is always rounded to one decimal place.

I would like ≈5,3 to be the actual value of 5.255.
I'm trying to figure this out for literally weeks now. Went through "Customer Defaults" multiple times. Closest I found was trying to add a new Drafting Standard:

Added new Drafting Standard where I changed Dimensions -> Text -> Decimal Places to 5. But that didn't work either. Tried restarting NX, creating new models etc... nothing works!
Isn't there a simple way to change number of decimal places on Sketch dimensions?
Thanks!

This can be done by the following steps:

select the dimension you want to change the displayed decimal places.
Invoke Settings from the MB3 menu (right mouse button).
Go to Text-->Units and you can change the decimal places.

Note that you can select multiple dimensions in step 1 to make the change for multiple dimensions at once.

